# graphical representation of Maxwell velocity distribution law

Tags: kinematics, dirac-delta-distributions

I have read Maxwell's distribution law it is the probabilistic representation of no. Of particles having velocity between $c$ to $c+DC$,through this representatation we can get the number of particle having velocity between velocity range $c$ to $c+DC$.The expression of this distribution is
$$dnc=4πnA^3e^{-bc^2}c^2dc$$
And the probability distribution function is $f(c)$ and total probability is $f(c)dc$ so we get $dnc=f(c)dc$

We know graphical representation of probability distribution function

Now we all know this graphical representation now I have two problems

1. If I draw a line parallel to $c$ axis
   Then that line will cut the curve in two different points means for two different value of velocity  we get same value of probability distribution function $f(c)$ so what the physical significance of this case in kinetic theory?
2. My second doubt is I can not determine the graphical representation
   between $dnc$ vs $c$ what kind of curve it is?

Comment: Can you add MathJax (LaTeX) to this? You can use [this tutorial](http://physics.stackexchange.com/help/notation) for help.

Comment: 1. I can't see any significance to this. It would be true for *any* probability distribution that is zero at the two extremes. 2. I don't think I understand this question. You say yourself "We know graphical representation of probability distribution function", so...

Comment: I asked the graph between dncdnc and c

Comment: You can't [plot it](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+x%5E2*exp(-x%5E2)+for+0%3Cx%3C4) or [look it up](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=maxwell+boltzmann+distribution&espv=2&biw=1871&bih=995&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwip6ITHq9LLAhUGXhoKHV1hDEsQ_AUIBigB) yourself? Or am I missing something?

Comment: I asked what will be the graph of dnc vs c